# Cannot call assocation inside method missing. Help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple acts_as style module, that is included in ActiveRecord::Base. The purpose of this module is to:

1. add an has_one association to an ActiveRecord model
2. add a missing method to instances, that will direct any missing methods to the associated instance.

Here is the example module:

```
module TestModule

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def test_me_out
      has_one :text_page
      send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      Rails.logger.debug "#{method}"
      #text_page.send(method, *args, &block)
      text_page
    end

  end
end
```

And the way I might use it in an AR model...

```
Class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  test_me_out
end
```

**The problem is, if the *method_missing* method in the module is run, it immediately causes a "stack level too deep" error inside the method_missing....**

```
  app/lib/test_module.rb:24:in `method_missing'
  app/lib/test_module.rb:24:in `method_missing'
  app/lib/test_module.rb:24:in `method_missing'
  app/lib/test_module.rb:24:in `method_missing'
  app/lib/test_module.rb:24:in `method_missing'
  ...
```

The method that is missing is 'id' ?!? You'll notice that I've commented out the example line of code that would send the missing method to the associated class - text_page.send(method, *args, &block) - since just calling the association - text_page - is enough to trigger the stack level too deep error.

Can anyone spot the error?

PS. Of course this is a boiled down example of the actual module and use case, however this illustrates the error, and fails wonderfully.

---

**SOLUTION**

Big thanks the Alex for the save. The ActiveRecord Id is generated dynamically using the method missing block. The following code works as it let the :id method missing to pass down into super:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
   if method != :id && text_page.respond_to?(method)
      text_page.send(method, *args, &block)
   else
      super
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik - If I remember correctly, AR uses method_missing to define attributes accessors and the like on the class, e.g. they are not hard coded. They are stored in instance variables, but the .id and .id= methods are defined on-the-fly. As a result, I'd recommend defining a way to match missing methods that you want referred to the associated interface.

Comment: You could possibly use
if text_page.methods.include?(method)
  text_page.send(method, *args, &block)
else
  super(method, *args, &block)
end

Comment: Hey Alex, I misunderstood your suggestion at first read. Have a quick look at the bottom of this gist: https://gist.github.com/787122 . I do a quick respond_to? check that the method exists in the associated class before delegating the method. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I think the important thing to note is that any call to the associated model from within the method_missing block is 'stack overflowing' :)

Comment: Yeah Eric, that is what I meant :) That code looks like it would work.